# Trouble using transforms.FiveCrop()/TenCrop() in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to increase my CNN’s performance and thus i decided to “play” with some transformations in order to see how they affect my model. I read that FiveCrop() and TenCrop() might help because they generate extra data to train on. However, when i try to train the model, using one of the transformations mentioned above, i get the following error:

TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got < class ‘tuple’>

The documentation of those transformations, only states a note for the test procedure, any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

```
train_transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ColorJitter(),
     transforms.TenCrop(32),
     transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465), (0.247, 0.243, 0.261))
     ])

train = datasets.CIFAR10(root = './data',
                  train = True,
                  transform = train_transform,
                  download = True)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train,
                                      batch_size = 1250,
                                      shuffle = True)

for epoch in range(num_of_iterations):
  correct = 0
  acc = 0.0
  running_loss = 0.0
  for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
      images = images.requires_grad_().to(device)
      labels = labels.to(device)
```

The error occurs on the line of the second for-loop

Comment: This means that the input to this transformation is wrong. It's hard to tell much from just knowing it's a tuple, but chances are you are passing in a tuple `(image, label)` instead of just `image`. Can you provide a code example how do you instantiate your dataloader and how you actually use the crop transforms?

Answer (score 1):

Right, your error is coming from `transforms.ToTensor()`, which is directly downstream of your `TenCrop` in the composed transformation. It expects an image but gets a tuple of crops instead. You should follow a procedure similar to the one shown in the documentation not only for testing but also for training in order to reorganize your images into the expected format of `[batch, feature_maps, width, height]`.

As a side note, CIFAR10 is already 32x32 pixels so taking 32x32 crops is an identity operation. Your `FiveCrop` effectively just repeats the same image 5 times and `TenCrop` repeats it 5 times plus adds 5 flipped versions. You should either reduce the size of crops or find out a different data augumentation scheme to see improvement with your networks generalization.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Jatentaki, your problem is that you are calling `ToTensor` on the output of `TenCrop`, which is a tuple and not a numpy array. Here is the example from the documentation of how to use `TenCrop`:

```
transform = Compose([
   TenCrop(size), # this is a list of PIL Images
   Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([ToTensor()(crop) for crop in crops])) # returns a 4D tensor
])
#In your test loop you can do the following:
input, target = batch # input is a 5d tensor, target is 2d
bs, ncrops, c, h, w = input.size()
result = model(input.view(-1, c, h, w)) # fuse batch size and ncrops
result_avg = result.view(bs, ncrops, -1).mean(1) # avg over crops
```